# Where was this photo taken?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

Still from a youtube video. The church just above the trees on the right could be Eastern European.
The peaks have snow, so possibly Alps or Carpathians?!

[image]

Comment: A link to the YouTube video in question here might provide some context.

Comment: @Snow I expected that question. It doesn't. It is a video containing an old song, with unrelated pictures. (the song is Dutch, the landscape certainly not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be [Bled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bled), Slovenia. Compare the mountain on the left side of [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bled_island_July_2005.jpg). I haven't been able to figure out which church it is.

So, the Julian Alps.

Comment: Yes, you are right!!! I thought it looked familair, that is why I posted it in the first place.

Comment: I've been looking at your picture and google streetview. I've concluded that the picture is facing east from Bled. This means it is not the Julian Alps, but the Kamnik–Savinja Alps we see.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure which mountain it is. Yes, roughly east (the island and the castle are in a line NE).